# FFMPEG not extracting yuv colorspace images

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, yuv

I am using FFMPEG to extract images from MXF videos. I am interested in extracting tiff format images with the YUV (preferably 422) color space. The MXF videos are of the YUV color space. Hence why I want to continue to work in that color space. I have tried:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mxf -pix_fmt yuv422p f%10d.tiff
```

However the output images appear to be of the RGB color space. I use ImageMagick and the command line:

```
identify -verbose output.tiff
```

Which informs me that the image files are of the RGB color space. I have googled and tried variations to my FFMPEG command line but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

ffmpeg console output as requested:
[First part of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzIL8.png)
[Second part of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RFcs.png)

imagemajick identify (partial) result:
(I'm not allowed to post more than two links*)

Comment: Please post the full console output of the ffmpeg command.

Comment: Your ffmpeg version is probably too old to support yuv encoding in tiff.

Comment: I've added screenshots of the console output @Mulvya
The version is 2.8.4 - PaulB.Mahol (I can only tag one member apparently)

Comment: I changed it to "ffmpeg -i video.mxf -vcodec copy -pix_fmt yuv422p f%10d.tiff" and it identifes with a YUV colorspace, but with red, green and blue channel depths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `ffprobe output.tiff`. It should report a YUV pixel format.

Don't confuse pixel format with [absolute color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_space), sRGB, if it's the source colorspace, will remain the destination colorspace as well. The YUV pixel formats are a way of decoupling luminance/intensity from chromaticity/hue, which aids with efficiently compressing a video signal.

From [Y'CbCr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr):

> Y′CbCr is not an absolute color space; rather, it is a way of encoding
>   RGB information.

Comment: Thanks. ffprobe reports YUV. However, I've been double-checking on matlab: [[[ a = imread('f20.tiff'); b = a; b(:,:,1) = 0; ]]] and displaying the images. I can visibly/subjectively identify that a colour channel is being loss. The first channel of YUV should be luminance, so the original colour of the picture should generally remain (without intensity differences). However I can identify that the red channel is being lost - the colour of the picture is changing as if its RGB. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Edit: Actually, I just realised Matlab is just interpreting the values as if its RGB despite it being YUV. So... I would need to do a conversion first perhaps. Unless matlab can identify yuv and work with that?

Comment: Don't know Matlab but looks like there are dedicated [functions](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiff.read.html) for TIFF.